# Assembly language how to increment multi-digit decimal ASCII strings?

Tags: assembly, x86

so I have this part of the code

```
    mov SI, 0002
    mov ah, INPUT[SI]
    INC SI
    mov al, INPUT[SI]
    sub AX, 3030h
    aad
    inc al
    cmp byte ptr INPUT[0002], 39h
    jne OTHER



OTHER: aam
       add ax, 3030h
       mov INPUT[0003], al
       mov INPUT[0002], ah
```

where the input is the user input.
What this code does is to increment a 2 digit number,
my problem, when a three digit number is to be incremented.

Example:
Input: 98
output: 99

Input: 99
Output: 110

Desired results:
Input: 99
Output: 100

Comment: `aam`? `aad`? Holy 8086, Batman!

Comment: After converting both input digits to 0-9 integers in AX, you only increment the low one, without carry from AL to AH.  So your code would do `39` -> `30` instead of `40`.  Handling 3-digit results in a separate and harder problem.  Also, `jne OTHER` is useless because both sides of the branch (fall-through or taken) are the same place.  Also, the first 4 instructions could just be `mov ax, [INPUT+2]` / `xchg al,ah`.  (Or more efficiently, `rol ax, 8`, unless you need backwards compat with 8086 which didn't have immediate rotates with count > 1)

Comment: If the input is guaranteed to be only 2 digits (or even easier, exactly 2 digits), then `'99'` is the only special case and you could just check for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `inc` command, such as: `inc var`, however I see you've used this in your code to no avail. If `inc` doesn't work for you, there's also `add destination, source`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler if you leave all the carry related stuff to the CPU, I'd suggest to completely convert the input number to an integer, incrementing and then converting back to string and output it. I want you to think about this so I will just give you a C-like pseudocode and help you converting it to assembly if you need more help ;)

```
int nInput = 0;

// Converting to decimal
if( input[ 0 ] > '9' ) input[ 0 ] -= 'a' + 10;
else input[ 0 ] -= '0'
nInput += input[ 0 ];

if( input[ 1 ] > '9' ) input[ 1 ] -= 'a' + 10;
else input[ 1 ] -= '0'
nInput += input[ 1 ] * 16;

if( input[ 2 ] > '9' ) input[ 2 ] -= 'a' + 10;
else input[ 2 ] -= '0'
nInput += input[ 2 ] * 256;

if( input[ 3 ] > '9' ) input[ 3 ] -= 'a' + 10;
else input[ 3 ] -= '0'
nInput += input[ 3 ] * 4096;

// Incrementing :)
nInput += 1;

// Converting back to string
char output[ 5 ];

int digit = nInput & 15;
if( digit > 9 ) digit += 'a' + 10;
else digit += '0';
output[0] = digit;

digit = ( nInput & 255 ) / 16;
if( digit > 9 ) digit += 'a' + 10;
else digit += '0';
output[1] = digit;

digit = ( nInput & 4095 ) / 256
if( digit > 9 ) digit += 'a' + 10;
else digit += '0';
output[2] = digit;

digit = ( nInput & 65535 ) / 4096;
if( digit > 9 ) digit += 'a' + 10;
else digit += '0';
output[3] = digit;

output[4] = 0;
```

This is the code you should implement in assembly. Don't do it blindly, think about what you're doing and why!

**Hint:** You can avoid all those multiplications and divisions, just look carefully at what you divide or multiply by :)